# MongoDB. query from three collections

Tags: mongodb

There are collections

```
city: {"_id", "name"}

company: {"_id", "name", "cityID"}

comments: {"_id", "text", "companyID"}
```

You must select the last 10 comments on companies of a certain city.

Now I select _id first of all companies in the city, and then the 10 comments received on _id
Here's the code:

```
$ db-> execute ('function () {

var result = {};

var company = [];
result.company = [];
db.company.find ({"city": "msk"}, {"title": 1, "_id": 1}). forEach (function (a) {
result.company [a._id] = Object.deepExtend (a, result [a._id]);
company.push (a._id);
});


var comments = [];
result.comments = [];
db.comments.find ({"company": {"$ in": company}}). sort ({"createTime": -1}). limit (10). forEach (function (a) {
result.comments [a._id] = Object.deepExtend (a, result [a._id]);
comments.push (a._id);
});


return result;

} ');
```

Esti's a better option to do what I need?
Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Properly indenting your code would be helpful.

Comment: I would also advise not using [server-side JavaScript](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using{{db.eval%28%29}}) for this purpose (that links is filled with caveats and considerations). There's no reason you can't issue the first query with `MongoCollection::find()`, build up an array of company ID's in PHP, and then issue a second query.

Comment: Why is it better to do it in PHP, a server than JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code

```
db.comments
  .find({"company": {"$in": company}})
  .sort({"createTime": -1})
  .limit(10)
```

is only fetching the last 10 comments overall for the specified city, rather than the last 10 for each company.  Is this what you want?  If so, then it might make sense to just store a "city" field for each comment, and just query the comments collection based on city.

If you want to last 10 for each company, with your current schema you will have to make individual queries on the comments collection for each relevant company.

What is the use case for your data?

Edit:

In a relational database model, you would be able to execute a JOIN query that would get you the information from both tables (companies and comments) in one query.  However, since MongoDB does not support joins, if you want to be able to fetch the information you need in a single query then you need to denormalize the data a little bit by storing a city field in the comments collection.

Comment: 10 most recent comments is in the city. I thought that would add a city in the comments, but it's the same - denormalization. In this case kokrutnom maybe this is normal, but there may be situations and well-connected data. Is there no way but to get all the id and use $in?

Comment: Not the way your schema is set up.  Since the city a company is in seems very unlikely to change, I think is an acceptable violation of normalization to put the city within the comments.

Comment: Do not plan to ever mongodb in future versions, adding support "JOIN" or something similar?